# Have rails ignore a specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `shared/` folder in my `my_app/public/` folder and when attempting to access it via www.my_app.com/shared, I see:

`no route matches '/shared', :method => 'get'`

This makes sense, but I want rails to ignore this folder and just let me use Apache to render a standard directory listing here.

Any way to do this?

Comment: We need more details about your setup.  It sounds like you have apache servicing requests and then handing them off to rails.  Is that via mongrels?  phusion?  etc.  What version of rails, apache?  What OS?

Comment: Well there is an Apache web server but my rails app is deployed via passenger.

my_app is running on my_app.com which is desired, but I'd like my_app.com/shared to load a standard Apache directory listing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you should need to do is disable Passenger for that directory, and make sure `Indexes` (directory listings) are allowed. In your Apache <VirtualHost> config block, add:

```
<Location /shared>
  PassengerEnabled off
  Options +Indexes
</Location>
```

Comment: I'm on a shared server and the server admins would not add this to the httpd.conf for me. Fortunately, I was able to find a rather suitable work around with mod_rewrite and a subdomain. Thanks though :)